# What is the Aasimar Trait?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, racial-traits, aasimar

I make my first PF2e character and choose an Aasimar Heritage.

Now they write in the description:

> You gain the aasimar trait, in addition to the traits from
> your ancestry.

But I cannot find an Aasimar Trait anywhere. Could anyone help me where to find it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Traits are (mostly) descriptors.

Specifically, "Aasimar" is an [Ancestry Trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=119).

> These descriptors have no mechanical benefit, but they’re important for determining how certain spells, effects, and other aspects of the game interact with your character.

Essentially, if an effect says that it only affects Aasimar or doesn't affect Aasimar, that's how you 'tell' if it works.

---

In addition to defining [Traits](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx), such as ancestry, class, and energy types, there are a handful of Traits that have rules associated with them. The most obscure ones that are often relevant are [Incapacitation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=93) and [Focused](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=74), although there are also Action/Activity Traits that are usually defined where needed (such as in the Class section) such as [Flourish](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=73), [Open](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=123), and [Press](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=133).

Answer (score 7):

See Advanced Player's Guide pg. 266

> A creature with this trait has the aasimar versatile heritage. Aasimars are planar scions descended from celestial beings. An ability with this trait can be used or selected only by aasimars.

You gain access to these feats.

> Aasimar's Mercy, Agathion Magic, Angelic Magic, Angelkin, Archon Magic, Azata Magic, Blessed Blood (Aasimar), Call of Elysium, Celestial Eyes, Celestial Lore, Celestial Resistance, Celestial Strikes, Celestial Wings, Celestial Word, Divine Countermeasures, Emberkin, Empyreal Blessing, Enforced Order, Eternal Wings (Aasimar), Flame Jump, Garuda Magic, Garuda's Squall, Halo, Healer's Halo, Idyllkin, Lawbringer, Musetouched, Peri Magic, Plumekith, Purge Sins, Radiate Glory, Summon Celestial Kin, Tranquil Sanctuary, Truespeech

For example, celestial wings, p36, is as such.

> With effort, you can call forth magical wings from your back, similar in appearance to those of your celestial forebears. These wings remain for 10 minutes. You gain a fly Speed equal to your Speed while you've manifested your wings.

Without this trait or some other access, you can't use this feat.